# How to count YTD days in my MDX query

Tags: mdx, ssas-2008

I've below `MDX` query which gives me `YTD` amount for each my device perfectly, but I want count of those `YTD` days taken in consideration while calculating `YTD` amount.

How can I achieve those `YTD` days counts in my query?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Settlement Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      YTD
      (
        [Settlement Date].[Calendar].[Settlement Calendar Month].&[201412]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  [Settlement Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Device].[DeviceID].Children ON ROWS
FROM [cube1]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[amount];
```

OR

you can use below `AW MDX` query while making changes which give same results as my above query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] AS 
    Aggregate(YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015])) 
SELECT 
  [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] ON COLUMNS
 ,[Product].[Category].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Order Quantity];
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a little swapped around but hopefully heading in the direction you require:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] AS 
    Aggregate(YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].[March 2007])) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DaysCompleteCurrYear] AS 
    Descendants
    (
      YTD([Date].[Calendar].[Month].[March 2007])
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
     ,SELF
    ).Count 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[DaysCompleteCurrYear]
   ,[Measures].[Order Quantity]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Product].[Category].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD];
```

If we put the target month into a single member set then the family relationships are preserved and we can use that set in the custom measures:

```
WITH 
  SET [targMth] AS 
    {[Date].[Calendar].[Month].[March 2007]} 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD] AS 
    Aggregate(YTD([targMth].Item(0).Item(0))) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DaysCompleteCurrYear] AS 
    Descendants
    (
      YTD([targMth].Item(0).Item(0))
     ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date]
     ,SELF
    ).Count 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[DaysCompleteCurrYear]
   ,[Measures].[Order Quantity]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Product].[Category].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar].[CalendarYTD];
```